# where can I find the actual code for the JQuery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a place where I can see the actual code and how the JQuery methods were constructed? Like for example, how the fadeIn() and slideUp() methods were coded? I want it for learning / studying purposes and I tried looking at the JQuery.js file and it is way to hard to read. I then tried going and reading here:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js

but then I couldn't find the actual code for the slideUp and fadeIn methods.

Comment: That's because the fadeIn and slideUp methods call the animation method

Comment: It's there, it's just disguised -- search for `fadeIn` and look around there carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code you'll see that slideUp and fadeIn methods are dynamically created via:

```
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show"),
    slideUp: genFx("hide"),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle"),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

As described, these are just shortcut methods that use the jquery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. For each of the properties inside the jQuery.each method above, the value is passed as the props parameter, which is passed to the props field of this.animate. genFx returns an Object with properties so that works the same way. You would want to inspect the animate function and genFx functions as @Kyle described to get a better idea of what is going on in these functions.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is it (it's in the file linked; would post this as a comment, but it's too difficult to decipher):

```
// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show"),
    slideUp: genFx("hide"),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle"),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
    }, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

genFx refers to this method (for slideup\down):

```
// Generate parameters to create a standard animation
function genFx( type, includeWidth ) {
    var which,
        attrs = { height: type },
        i = 0;

    // if we include width, step value is 1 to do all cssExpand values,
    // if we don't include width, step value is 2 to skip over Left and Right
    includeWidth = includeWidth? 1 : 0;
    for( ; i < 4 ; i += 2 - includeWidth ) {
        which = cssExpand[ i ];
        attrs[ "margin" + which ] = attrs[ "padding" + which ] = type;
    }

    if ( includeWidth ) {
        attrs.opacity = attrs.width = type;
    }

    return attrs;
}
```

I'm guessing it calls into other methods which cover the common functionality. This is the only declaration I found though.